# Assign class to data frame after clustering

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I used k-means cluster algorithm on a data-frame df1 and the result is shown in the picture below.

```
library(ade4)
df1 <- data.frame(x=runif(100), y=runif(100))
plot(df1)
km <- kmeans(df1, centers=3)
kmeansRes<-factor(km$cluster)
s.class(df1,fac=kmeansRes, add.plot=TRUE, col=rainbow(nlevels(kmeansRes)))
```

[image]
Is there a possibility to add to the data frame information from which cluster does the observation come from?

Comment: `df1$cluster <- km$cluster` should work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already have the information you want:

```
kmeansRes<-factor(km$cluster)
```

just add it to your data frame as additional column.

```
df1$cluster <- km$cluster
```